# Python find number steps to allocate values to elements in list

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I am trying to reassign values for elements in list and try to find how many steps to do it.

For example i have 5 elements in list [1,1,1,1,6] Mean value is 2

I want to replace all elements [2,2,2,2,2]

This require 4 moves to make all same.

```
 First Step    [1,1,1,1,6] -> [2,1,1,1,5]
 Second Step    [2,1,1,1,5] -> [2,2,1,1,4]
 Third Step    [2,2,1,1,4] -> [2,2,2,1,3]
 Fourth Step    [2,2,2,1,3] -> [2,2,2,2,2]
```

I am not able to write an algorithm for this any help or hint is appreciated.

Here is my python code to get input :

```
test_cases=input()
packets=[]
candies=[]
for _ in range(test_cases):
    packet=input()
    for i in range(0,packet):
        candy=input()
        candies.append(candy)
    print candies
    if sum(candies)%packet==0:
        print (sum(candies)/packet),"mean"
    else:
        print "-1"
```

Comment: So your output should be `[2,2,2,2,2]` ?

Comment: The *mean* is 2, the median is 1. How is the "number of moves" required to change `[1, 1, 1, 1, 6]` into `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]` equal to 4?? Five changes are required.

Comment: i know the output but i want to write algorithm to find how many steps needed to make alll same

Comment: sorry i typed wrongly its mean not median ur right @BrianO

Comment: Don't you already *have* an algorithm? How did you solve the example? Look at it this way: what is the process being followed in the four steps you have shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
packets=[]
flag=True
while(flag):
    packet=input()
    candies=[]
    if packet == -1:
        flag= False
    else:
        for i in range(0,packet):
            candy=input()
            candies.append(candy)
        packets.append(candies)
for candies in packets:
    count = 0
    sum_candy = sum(candies)
    length = len(candies)
    if sum_candy%length==0:
        for ele in candies:
            if ele > (sum_candy/length) :
                diff = ele -(sum_candy/length)
                count += diff
        print count
    else:
        print "-1"`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like by "moves" you mean, maximum difference of an element in the list from the mean value. Thus:

```
from math import ceil
mean = sum(lst)/len(lst)
diffs = [ceiling(abs(k - mean)) for k in lst]
num_moves = max(diffs)
```

However, I'm not sure you actually mean "mean":) The mean of a list of integers is in general not an integer. How many "moves" would you say are required to get from 3.5 to 5 -- will that take 1, or 2 "moves"? The above assumes it will take 2 "moves".

In case you actually mean "median", which *will* be an integer, the following approach works:

```
from math import ceil

median = sorted(lst)[len(lst)//2]
diffs = [abs(k - median)) for k in lst]
num_moves = max(diffs)
```

Comment: If I'm wrong about my interpretation of "move", let me know, and I'll emend or kill the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hint using it i got the answer

Comment: Yw... I'm still not sure what a "move" is though! Is the answer correct or not quite?

Comment: i think i did not explain well enough  about the problem and solution i need ,anyway thanks for the hint @Briano

Comment: I see, it's more complicated still. OK.